# compute the smallest affine subspace containing $S$, where $S=\{(1,1,1),(2,3,4),(1,2,3),(2,1,0)\}$ is a set of vectors in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

I've started to study convexity to enchance my optimization skills.

Given a set $S=\{(1,1,1),(2,3,4),(1,2,3),(2,1,0)\}$ of vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ an exercise asks to compute the smallest affine subspace containing $S$.

By a lemma I know that the affine hull of S: $$\text{aff}(S) = \{ \lambda_1 v_1 + \dots + \lambda_m v_m \mid m \ge 1, v_1, \ldots, v_m \in S, \lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_m = 1 \}$$ is the smallest affine subspace containing $S$.

However, I guess the answer is not just writing what I just wrote with $v_1,\ldots, v_m$ substituted with elements of $S$. On the other hand, how can I specify the affine hull differently, that is computing it ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "affine subspace"? I have seem multiple uses of similar phrases.

Comment: A non-empty subset $M \subset \mathbb R^3$ is called an affine subspace if $(1-t)u + tv \in M$ for every $u,v \in M$ and $t\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: OK, got it. Then @Michael's suggestion is an excellent one: you should follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to your lemma, your idea seems trivial, but is totally fine! The affine space $M$ generated by $S$ is
\begin{align*}
M=\{a(1,1,1)+b(2,3,4)+c(1,2,3)+d(2,1,0)\ |\ a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R,a+b+c+d=1\}.
\end{align*}
Taking $a=1-b-c-d$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
M=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1+b+d\\1+2b+c\\1+3b+2c-d\end{pmatrix}\ |\ b,c,d\in\mathbb R\right\}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\mbox{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}\right\}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\mbox{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}\right\}.
\end{align*}
The last equality is true, since
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}=2\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
and the remaining two vectors are linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

You have $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$.  An affine space containing those points is $v_1+\text{ span }\{v_2-v_1,v_3-v_1,v_4-v_1\}$ which is $v_1$ plus an ordinary subspace.
Find a basis for that subspace.

Comment: How do you get to this ? What is your reasoning ?

Comment: $\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\lambda_3v_3+\lambda_4v_4=$ $(1-\lambda_2-\lambda_3-\lambda_4)v_1+...=v_1+\lambda_2(v_2-v_1)+\lambda_3(v_3-v_1)+\lambda_4(v_4-v_1)$